# Contact form 7 Class/ID

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

Hi I'm currently making a website using wordpress. And I'm are working with multiple contact forms. 
I chose to use contact form 7 and made serveral forms but the problem lies with the styling. 
When I target the contact form with

```
.wpcf7-form {
    height:600px;
    padding-left:20%;
    width:100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(250, 118, 34, 1) , rgba(243, 49, 27, 1) );
}
```

Of course it targets every single form but my question is can I give it a class or ID? Cause I cant find it in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply class and id both as per your requirement in form tag of contact form 7.

You might have already put the short code of contact form 7. Right? There are two parameters to set form id and form class to contact form 7  element.

These parameters are: html_id and html_class. Example:

```
[contact-form-7 id="your_auto_genarated_id" title="Contact form 1" html_id="contact-form-1234" html_class="form contact-form"]
```

For complete guide see: https://contactform7.com/faq/can-i-add-id-and-class-attributes-to-a-form-element/

Comment: Ahh thanks that helps alot! last question those html_id and html_class are editable?

Comment: yes. Those both are just a kind of parameter's value. So of course you can edit it. :-)